# Transit Visa - Heathrow, London

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, lhr

My nationality is India. I have been working in Belgium. Now I'm leaving Belgium permanently, so I surrendered my Resident Permit and got a Model 8 and Appendix 37 from commune. I am travelling from Brussels -> Heathrow -> Chennai and I am leaving Belgium permanently. Can I travel with Model 8 instead of a transit visa through Heathrow airport?

Comment: What is "model 8"? What is your nationality?

Comment: My nationality is India. I stay in Belgium for Work and i had Resident permit. Now i am surrendered my Resident permit in Commune of Belgium and got Model 8 and Appendix 37 from them which  states that i permanently leave the country.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your parameters through [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa), and it appears to me you do need a visa, with the type depending on whether you need to pass through immigration, for example to collect and recheck bags. I suggest you do the check yourself.

There are clear lists of documents that would allow you to transit without a visa. The ones in your question do not appear on the lists. "a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland", which you used to have, does appear, but to depend on that you would have to currently have one.

Comment: As i am transiting via same British airways, i don't have  to collect and recheck the bags. My flight is tomorrow. Would it be possible to get transit visa on Brussels airport?

Comment: @KarthickS No you cannot. You need to provide your Biometric details. Best would be to postpone your flight or get one which is from Belgium.

Comment: There may not be any direct flights, but @KarthickS could look over the possible connection airports to pick one that either does not require a visa for transit by citizens of India, or for which they can get one easily and quickly.

Comment: There are many flights to India from various airports in the Schengen area. It's not at all necessary to go via the UK.